# Sharing update on linkedin doesn't scrape/pull page title and content

Tags: html, web, linkedin-api, social-networking, addthis

I am working on a website and we have a requirement for allowing our clients to share their pages on LinkedIn.
We have implemented a share button using AddThis which seems to work fine for LinkedIn, but manually sharing any of the pages that work fine with LinkedIn (via the Share Update functionality of our accounts) doesn't seem to work as expected.
When manually sharing a link, the link to the page is properly generated, however the title and descriptive text of the page (we're talking about news articles) are not filled all of the time.
It seems that most of the time we are getting the 404 page's title and content, and sometimes just the 404 page's title and the targeted page's content.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? If so, could you tell me where the information is pulled from and how?

Comment: Do you have any kind of user-agent specific redirection in place or so ? I mean there must be a reason why linkedin's lookup ends up on your 404 error page...

Comment: We are using Sitecore and we are implementing a processor for handling 404 redirection if an URL does not match any data item in the content structure. Unless no item is found, the processor does not tamper with the HTTP response, and allows the CMS to freely display the right page.

Comment: @Bartdude I can view the page in a browser window and I can share the page using our AddThis share button. It seems that the error only occurs when trying to manually share the page.

Answer (score 0):

To prepopulate a preview of your site's `title`, `image`, etc., you'll need to use `og:` tags, for instance...

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />`

You would insert these into the `<head>` block of your HTML.

Source: [**LinkedIn Developer Docs: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en).

You can verify that you implemented correctly by using the [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/) on your website's URL.